# 60fps and updating list. What to do?

Tags: python

I want to append a score to my "last_Score" list at the end of the game but it adds 60 items per second. I only want to have one item per game_over. Any ideas?

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Game, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.start_sound.play()
        self.init_vertical_line()
        self.init_horizontal_line()
        self.init_quad()
        self.init_hero()
        self.start_quads()
        self.quad_generation()
        if self.is_desktop():
            self.keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self.keyboard_hidden, self)
            self.keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down)
            self.keyboard.bind(on_key_up=self.on_keyboard_up)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1/60)

def update(self, dt):
        time_factor =  dt*60
        self.update_vertical_lines()
        self.update_horizontal_line()
        self.quad_update()
        self.quad_generation()
        self.update_hero()
        self.score_board()
       

def score_board(self):
        if self.game_over:
            self.end_score = self.score
            self.last_Score.append((self.end_score))
            if len(self.last_Score) > 10:
                del self.last_Score[:-2]
                print(self.last_Score)
```

Comment: I think you need to cancel the scheduled update once the game is over, or at least distinguish between the *game* being over and your *program* being done, if `update` should continue to run even after `self.game_over` becomes true.

Comment: I think you should set `self.game_over` to `False` in the if condition, because it seems to stay `True` all the time …

Answer (score 2):

I did it! My code down here.

```
def score_board(self):
        if self.game_over:
            self.end_score = self.score
            self.last_Score.append((self.end_score))
            if len(self.last_Score) > self.game_number:
                del self.last_Score[-1]
            try:
                self.last_Score_Label = "Your last score is" + str(self.last_Score[-2])
            except:
                self.last_Score_Label = "Your last score is " +  str(self.last_Score[-1])
            print(self.last_Score)
```

Answer (score 0):

A heavy-handed way to ensure `score_board` is only executed once:

1. Set `self.update_score = True` in `__init__`.
2. Redefine `score_board` as

   ```
   def score_board(self):
       if self.game_over:
           self.update_score = False
           self.end_score = self.score
           self.last_Score.append((self.end_score))
           if len(self.last_Score) > 10:
               del self.last_Score[:-2]
               print(self.last_Score)
   ```
3. Reset `self.update_score = True` when appropriate (when the game restarts?).